# Getting index out of range error. What is the correct way to declare a 2D list?

Tags: python, list

1st code:

```
l1 = [[0, 3, 4], [1, 2]]
l2 = ['cat', 'dog', 'hen', 'bull', 'tac']
l3 = [[]] * len(l1)
for i in range(len(l1)):
    for j in range(len(l1[i])):
        l3[i].insert(j,l2[l1[i][j]])
print(l3)
```

2nd code:

```
l1 = [[0, 3, 4], [1, 2]]
l2 = ['cat', 'dog', 'hen', 'bull', 'tac']
l3 = [[], []]
for i in range(len(l1)):
    for j in range(len(l1[i])):
        l3[i].insert(j,l2[l1[i][j]])
print(l3)
```

I want the output as in 2nd code. But I don't want l3 as `[[],[]]`. How can I define l3 in 1st code such that I don't get any index out of range error.

Comment: You can use `l3 = [[] for i in range(2)]`

Comment: Thanks. I tried many things but never thought of this :P

Comment: Here is another method: `l3 = list(map(lambda i: [], range(2)))`

Answer (score -1):

```
l1=[[0,3,4],[1,2]]
l2=['cat','dog','hen','bull','tac']
l3=[[] for i in range(len(l1))]
for i in range(len(l1)):
    for j in range(len(l1[i])):
        l3[i].insert(j,l2[l1[i][j]])
print(l3)

# output [['cat', 'bull', 'tac'], ['dog', 'hen']]
```